# How to get child of child value from firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

this is my realtime-database

[image: database].

I dont know how i can get the child value on profile. In this case i use reactjs and firebase.

```js
const Database = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fire.child("Profil").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        setData({ ...snapshot.val() });
      } else {
        setData({});
      }
    });
    return () => {
      setData({});
    };
  }, []);
  return (
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(data).map((id, index) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                <td>{data[id].email}</td>
        
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
export default Database;
```

Comment: which child value are you looking for?

Comment: Where is `fire` defined ?

Comment: user/id/profil/email

Comment: const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = fire.auth();
export default fire.database().ref();

Comment: Problem is your `Profil` node is not root but it's under some UID. Are you trying to get currently logged in users data ?

Comment: no, i want make a crud table. and i was an admin